# Change language of months in full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I change language of months in my fullcalendar? In month view and week view ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that :

monthNames and monthNamesShort

```
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNames/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNamesShort/
```

like :

```
monthNames: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```